# How can I get JSON data from a browser extension (Chrome) from another server?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am writing a browser extension that should periodically receive the exchange rate in the JSON format and place it in local storage.
But when I try to do this in the code of a page of any site, I get error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my.server.domain/currency.txt' from origin 'https://developer.mozilla.org' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Sample request code

```
$updateUrl = "hhttps://my.server.domain/currency.txt";
$.get($updateUrl).done(function($updData) {

});
```

The only place where I can run a script like this is in **popup.html**, but I need updates to be triggered automatically.
I tried to do it through Background but in **manifest v3** there is no such possibility anymore.

The only option is to periodically open the update.html extension page and perform updates in it, but this happens by opening a new tab, and I would like to do this in the background.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

In general, I wrote this in **background.js** and it works

```
fetch("https://my.server.domain/currency.txt")
.then((response) => {
    return response.json();
})
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

It remains now to figure out how to make the script periodically update the data, otherwise it works only once. But that is another story.